# Python matplotlib: legend gives wrong result for scatter

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I'm trying to visualize fashion MNIST dataset with different dimensional reduction techniques and I also want to attach the legend to resulted picture with so called real_labels which tells the real name of the label. For fashion MNIST real labels are:

```
real_labels = ['t-shirt','trouser','pullover','dress','coat','sandal','shirt','sneaker','bag','ankle boot']
```

I'm doing the plotting part inside of following fucntion:

```
def Draw_datasamples_to_figure(X_scaled, labels, axis):
    y = ['${}$'.format(i) for i in labels]
    num_cls = len(list(set(labels)))
    for (X_plot, Y_plot, y1, label1) in zip(X_scaled[:,0], X_scaled[:,1], y, labels):
        axis.scatter(X_plot, Y_plot, color=cm.gnuplot(int(label1)/num_cls),label=y1, marker=y1, s=60)
```

, where X_scaled tells x and y coordinate, labels are integer numbers (0-9) for class information and axis tells in which subplot window picture will be drawn.

The legend is drawn with following command:

```
ax3.legend(real_labels, loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```

Everything seems to work pretty well until the legend is drawn to picture. As you can see from picture in below, instead of numbers goes from 0 to 9, the chosen numbers in legend are arbitrary.

[image]

I know that the problem is probably in scatter part and I should implement it in another way but I hope that there is still something simple that I miss which can fix my implementation. I don't want either to use hand-made legend in where markers and names are defined in the code because I have also other datasets with different classes and real label names. Thanks in advance!

Comment: As usual it would help if you provided a [mcve]. I.e. a code one can run and see the undesired behaviour. (Don't use your real data, but fake some data inside the code)

Comment: I think you should just use `ax3.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))` because you have already assigned the labels in the for loop. Try it out.

Comment: ... yes but then you would need to assign the actual label like `label=label1, marker=y1` in the `scatter` call.